# Serialize and create one-to-one relation with parent_link true in django and django rest framework

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models, django-rest-framework

How to save the object with one-to-one relation and having parent_link=True using serializer. Below are my models and serializer having some fields from the actual model that I wanted to implement. I am not able to save the 'user' relation in the database. It is throwing the integrity error.

```
class Audit(models.Model):
   is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
   updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

   class Meta:
      abstract = True

class User(Audit):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'

    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.TextField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class UserProfile(User):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_profile'

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, parent_link=True,
                            primary_key=True)
    address = models.TextField(null=True)
    dob = models.DateField()
    language = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True) 

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['user', 'address', 'dob', 'language']
```

And the requested data looks like this.
{
"email": "abc@pqr.com",
"password": "1234",
"dob": "2021-12-11",
"language" : "English"
}

Answer (score 0):

You can pass user when saving serializer :

```py
serializer.save(user=<USER>)
```

Note that if you want to create user when creating user profile, you should override `create()` method in your serializer, first create your user, then create user profile, and pass created user to it

Comment: okay, Thanks!! By inheriting `create()` method I am able to create both `User` and `User Profile`  objects together. 

But  while serializing the `User Profile` objects I am not able to fetch `User`. 
According to this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField.parent_link) this should act as subclass but it is not. @Amin